# Android app crashes with configuration change

Tags: android

My android app is forced to run in landscape mode. My device never changes it's orientation and I'm not changing any configuration during runtime (at least not intentionally), nobody is touching the device during the run and yet, I'm seeing the app consistently crashes every 2-3 min with configuration change triggered prior to that:

```
2019-07-22 00:35:34.222 642-1695/? E/SurfaceFlinger: size mismatch (2960, 1440) > (1440, 2960)
2019-07-22 00:35:34.242 1135-1146/? I/ActivityManager: Config changes=20000480 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h748dp 560dpi nrml long hdr widecg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 171 - 1440, 2792) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} s.45}
2019-07-22 00:35:34.263 1135-1146/? I/ActivityManager: Override config changes=20000480 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h748dp 560dpi nrml long hdr widecg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 2621, 1440) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 171 - 1440, 2792) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} s.45} for displayId=0
2019-07-22 00:35:34.316 1135-1281/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=2, name='sec_touchscreen', size 1440x2960, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
2019-07-22 00:35:34.471 642-642/? E/SurfaceFlinger: [com.breel.wallpapers18.soundviz.wallpaper.variations.SoundVizWallpaperV2#0] rejecting buffer: bufWidth=2960, bufHeight=1440, front.active.{w=1440, h=2960}
2019-07-22 00:35:34.666 1410-1410/? W/StatusBar/NavBarView: *** Invalid layout in navigation bar (sizeChanged this=1440x168 cur=1384x168)
```

I'm thinking I could've messed up the layout somehow but I'm not sure if that's what causing the issue, in any case here is my layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <io.occo.vision.camera2.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/tele_texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <io.occo.vision.camera2.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/wide_texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <io.occo.vision.camera2.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view_wide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <io.occo.vision.camera2.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view_tele"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <io.occo.vision.camera2.OverlayView
        android:id="@+id/debug_overlay_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/unpin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="unpin"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="unpin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:text="version: 0.0.2"
        android:textAlignment="textStart" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Activity configuration at startup

```
  @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            );
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name="io.occo.vision.CameraActivity"
            android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
    </application>
```

My app is running on Pixel 3XL, Android 9 (Pi), API level: 28

Comment: did you set `orientation="landscape"` for this activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: that log does not look like a crash log

Comment: @bvk256 Yes, I did. Just updated the original question with the Manifest.xml

Comment: Add this in `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `<application`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko nevertheless that's the only log I'm getting at the crash.

Comment: @sanjeev thanks for your suggestion. How hardwareAccelerate=true supposed to help with orientation issue? btw, I tried, it didn't help

Comment: @LevonShirakyan well in my case, I gave h/w accelerated as true and worked when I save the instance state and not allow reloading when orientation changed. 
And btw, why have you given `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in manifest for `<activity>`??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried programmatically using `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE‍` within your class? If you are going to change it only on landscape rotation that is. And if you want it rotated on portrait also use

`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`: 
Orientation is determined by a physical orientation sensor: the display will rotate based on how the user moves the device. Ignores the user's setting to turn off sensor-based rotation. Corresponds to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`.

Answer (score 0):

**My android app is forced to run in landscape mode. My device never changes it's orientation and I'm not changing any configuration during runtime (at least not intentionally), nobody is touching the device during the run**

> **A:** Well it is because you have asked the layout to be forced to run with the orientation as landscape in `manifest` in the `<activity`
>   tag, `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.

**Q: nobody is touching the device during the run and yet, I'm seeing the app consistently crashes every 2-3 min with configuration change triggered prior to that:**

> **A:** If you want to set your orientation to landscape then you have to
>   design the page based on that. As you can see in the log `Config changes=20000480 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h748dp 560dpi`, these are just the different densities of screen and your layout is crashing because of that.

Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support for a clear and better understanding on designing the layouts.